# WKWebView's Intrinsic Content Size issue in iOS 13 beta

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, ios13, intrinsic-content-size

I am trying to get the height of WKWeb view when it gets loaded and change the height of the cell in table view using a delegate method.The below code works well till iOS 12 .

When I try to run in iOS 13 beta , the cell height keeps increasing as the intrinsic size keeps on increasing by one every time.

Is there any way to stop this ?

```
 override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        print("intrinsic content size id \(self.scrollView.contentSize.height)")
        self.delegate?.changeHeight(self.scrollView.contentSize.height,self.indexpathOfCell)
        return self.scrollView.contentSize
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been fixed in Xcode11 beta7 and intrinsicContentSize works as expected .

Comment: I see that the issue still exists in iPad OS 13